# How to import .sql file into MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, northwind

This is an assignment. I have to import a .sql file into MS Access. The file preferably will be NorthWind Database (.sql file). I have downloaded one from:
https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/releases/view/71634
and it contains a .sql file. 
What to do next?

(Please note that importing/connecting MS Access from/to MS SQL Server through ODBC is irrelevant to this problem. The problem is to import a generic .sql file)

Comment: Import `.sql` file directly in Access? As I know it is impossible. Only through another RDBMS.

Comment: If we're to help then more detail is required.  Can you include more detail from your assignment?  Bearing in mind that Stack Overflow isn't a site to do your homework, it would be good for you to include things you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's plain impossible without a major rewrite, and I seriously doubt if that is the assignment given to you.

The SQL for download is in *T-SQL* for building the complete database in *SQL Server*.

The Nortwind database is for download in an Access version if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to rewrite it, but you should be able to open it with any text editor like notepad.    Then you can copy and paste it into the sql view in the query designer.